# Elasticsearch & Spark Write Error with timestamp fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I need a way for the following timestamp to be written into Elasticsearch without error-ring out on the Error message. The code below reads in JSON file then writes to Elasticsearch.

My code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schemaDF = spark.read.json("/tmp/LTPD/schema.json")
schemaDF.printSchema()
val schema = schemaDF.schema


   //read from JSON file
   val streamingDF = spark
     .readStream
     .schema(schema)
     .json("/tmp/Directory/")
   streamingDF
     .writeStream
     .outputMode("append")
     .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
     .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(conf.getString("spark.trigger")))
     .start("indexname/ourdoctype").awaitTermination()
```

The code works for nulls within the timestamp field but complains when the json has a string with `2019-08-15T09:40:13+00:00` or `2020-03-02T15:13:26Z`.

Sample Json

```
{
  "name":"Jordan", 
  "date": "2019-06-01T00:00:00+00:00", 
  "gmt": "2020-03-02T15:13:26Z", 
  "skills":["Scala", "Spark", "Akka"]
}
```

I see the Exception:

```
failed to parse field [metaData.collectionDateUtc] of type [long] in
document with id org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException:
illegal_argument_exception: For input string: "2019-08-15T09:40:13+00:00"
```

Comment: Please let us see the mapping for this index

Comment: esConf = {
  "es.resource" = ourmappingkey
  "es.mapping.id" = key
  "es.mapping.exclude" = key
}

sparkConf = {
  "es.nodes" = OurServer
  "es.port" = OurPort
  "es.net.http.auth.user" = username
  "es.net.http.auth.pass" = pass
  "es.nodes.wan.only" = true
  "es.net.ssl" = true
  "spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation" = ${spark."outputDirectory"}/spark_checkpoints
  "spark.debug.maxToStringFields" = 1000
}

Comment: @KevinQuinzel the mapping is defined by the json file within the post.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't like that format, can you transform that date type in another type? maybe keep the value as a long, I think that is the type that they expect.

Comment: @PedroCorreiaLuís  that what I needed some assitance to do, basically to add within the stream a way to recursively transform all values of yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'. I think the 'Z' is the value it complains about

Answer (score 0):

you need to dump the data via spark as timestamp using (if your date field is in `String`)

```
.withColumn("date", to_timestamp($"date")
```

Also, you would need to change the mapping of your index as per mention in the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats)